# "Like" button in laravel doesn't change state until page refresh

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js

I created a "Like" functionality that is able to favorite a post (I know because I checked *Favorite Table* in DB after clicking "Like"). But after I hit the button, the button description stays the same rather than change to "Unlike" i.e the "Like" text persists after clicking the button. Currently, the state/button-text changes only after I manually reload/refresh the page. Please, I need help to make button state change when clicked, without having to manually refresh page. Many thanks.

\\

```
   **Model Post.php** -> contains method to check if post is favorited or not

        public function favorited()
        {
        return (bool) Favorite::where('user_id', Auth::id())
                    ->where('post_id', $this->id)
                    ->first();
        }


   **Model User.php**

      public function favorites()
      {
      return $this->belongsToMany(Post::class, 'favorites', 'user_id', 
      'post_id')->withTimeStamps();
      }


     **Controller**

     <?php

    namespace App\Http\Controllers;

    use App\Models\User;
    use App\Models\Post;
    use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
    use Illuminate\Http\Request;

    class FavoriteController extends Controller
    {
    
    public function __construct(){
      $this->middleware('auth');
    }

    public function store(User $user, $post){
      return auth()->user()->favorite_list()->toggle($post->favorites);
    }


    public function favoritePost(Post $post)
    {
      Auth::user()->favorites()->attach($post->id);
      return back();
    }


    public function unFavoritePost(Post $post)
    {
       Auth::user()->favorites()->detach($post->id);
       return back();
    }

    }


   **FavoriteButton.Vue Component**

      <template>
      <span>
      <a href="#" v-if="isFavorited" class="btn btn-success" @click.prevent="unFavorite(post)">
        Like
      </a>
      <a href="#" v-else @click.prevent="favorite(post)" class="btn btn-success">
        Unlike
      </a>
      </span>
      </template>

      <script>
      export default {
      props: ['post', 'favorited'],

   
      mounted() {
        this.isFavorited = this.isFavorite ? true : false;
      },



      computed: {
        isFavorite() {
            return this.favorited;
        },
      },


      data: function() {
        return {
            isFavorited: '',
        }
      },


   

       methods: {
        favorite(post) {
            axios.post('/favorite/'+post)
                .then(response => this.isFavorited = true)
                .catch(response => console.log(response.data));
        },

        unFavorite(post) {
            axios.post('/unfavorite/'+post)
                .then(response => this.isFavorited = false)
                .catch(response => console.log(response.data));
        }
       }
      }
      </script>


    **HTML** 
          @foreach($posts as $post)
           <div class="container">
               <div style=""   class="container">
                    <h5 style="display: inline">Status: </h5>
                    <h6 style="display: inline">{{$post->batch_no}}</h6>
                </div>
          <favorite-button
          :post="{{ $post->id }}"
          :favorited="{{ $post->favorited() ? 'true' : 'false' }}"
          ></favorite-button>
          </div>
          @endforeach
```

\\

Comment: When I removed the axios requests and just set the isFavorited to true or false the text changes correctly. Check developer tools for javascript errors or check the network tab, maybe backend request doesn't end succesfully.

Comment: Hello Siim, I don't quite get. Could you give an example. The axios requests are a necessity to hit a controller. Kindly clarify

Answer (score 0):

I tested the vue component and that seems to work. Could you try to modify your vue components methods to following code and testing it. Pay attention to the comma between URL and post data.

```
methods: {
  favorite(post) {
    axios.post('https://httpbin.org/post', post)
        .then(response => this.isFavorited = true)
        .catch(response => console.log(response.data));
  },

  unFavorite(post) {
    axios.post('https://httpbin.org/post', post)
        .then(response => this.isFavorited = false)
        .catch(response => console.log(response.data));
  }
}
```

If your like/unlike button will work with this (it did when I tried it) then your backend code is probably the culprit and not responding with successful response code.

[image]

Comment: Hi @Siim, I tried your code, but doesn't work for me. Take a look ->   `axios.post('/favorite/post', post) `

Comment: There's no reaction at all when I use the above. Button text and DB are unchanged.

Comment: Do you see successful response from backend in developer tools?